# Show images from folder to RecyclerView ,ImageViews,Gridview. single image and multiple

Tags: android, image, gridview

I want to make a application.
When I click on the button create a folder and open new activity and in new activity I add a button when click on button it pick the image one or multiple image pick and show it in `Grid View` and save in my created folder.
Now issue is that I want to these image load from folder where save that image and show in grid views.

Comment: Did you tried any thing?

Comment: yes sir i a tried from last 5 days

Comment: i pick the image and save in my create folder but i want to show that image in my grid views permanent but its not show from folder to gridviews

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Activity Results` API to pick `Uri` of single or multiple images from the Gallery:

You can check the sample code for the reference:

```
// Register Activity Result Contract
private val pickImagesLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(GetMultipleImageContent()) { uris: List<Uri> ->
        // Do your stuff here
    }


// Call from your activity
pickImagesLauncher.launch(arrayOf("image/jpeg", "image/png"))


// Activity Result Contract for selecting multiple images of supported mime types.
class GetMultipleImageContent : ActivityResultContract<Array<String>, List<Uri>>() {
    override fun createIntent(
        context: Context,
        input: Array<String>
    ): Intent {
        return Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            .setType("*/*")
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, input)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    }

    override fun getSynchronousResult(
        context: Context,
        input: Array<String>
    ): SynchronousResult<List<Uri>>? {
        return null
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): List<Uri> {
        return if (intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            emptyList()
        } else getClipDataUris(intent)
    }

    private fun getClipDataUris(intent: Intent): List<Uri> {
        // Use a LinkedHashSet to maintain any ordering that may be
        // present in the ClipData
        val resultSet = LinkedHashSet<Uri>()
        intent.data?.let { resultSet.add(it) }
        when {
            intent.clipData == null && resultSet.isEmpty() -> {
                return emptyList()
            }
        }
        intent.clipData?.let { clipData ->
            for (i in 0 until clipData.itemCount) {
                clipData.getItemAt(i).uri?.let { uri ->
                    resultSet.add(uri)
                }
            }
        }
        return ArrayList(resultSet)
    }
}
```